# Inserting content to wp_editor tinyMCE not adding line breaks to editor

Tags: ajax, wordpress, tinymce, wp-editor

I am inserting content into a wp_editor via ajax response. I select the record I want to edit from a drop down and this populates all of the fields I want to edit. This ends up inserting the wp_editor content without line breaks. If I manually add the line breaks and save it, it saves fine and displays the content correctly. But the next time I go to edit that item, it then inserts into the editor without the line breaks so I have to manually add the line breaks again.

This is what I am using to create the wp_editor.

```
$args = array(
 'textarea_rows' => 15,
 'textarea_name' => 'customEditor',
 'media_buttons' => false
);

wp_editor( '', 'customEditor', $args );
```

This is how I am inserting the content to the editor from the ajax response.

```
tinyMCE.get( "customEditor" ).setContent(result[i].services);
```

It is also escaping quotes and single quotes when inserting into the editor. I have a feeling this might be from the ajax response json encode. So thinking I need to do something with this content before sending it to the editor. Anyone know a solution to handle this?

Here is what the ajax response looks like in console

```
"services":"Here is a link <a href=\\\"http:\/\/www.example.com\\\">http:\/\/www.example.com<\/a>\r\n\r\nthis is a new line\r\nthis is a new line\r\nthis is a new line\r\nthis is a new line\r\nthis is a new line\r\nthis is a new line\r\nthis is a new line\r\nthis is a new line\r\nthis is a new line\r\nthis is a new line\r\nthis is a new line\r\nthis is a new line\r\nthis is a new line\r\nthis is a new line\r\nthis is a new line\r\nthis is a new line\r\nthis is a new line\r\nthis is a new line\r\nthis is a new line\r\nthis is a new line"
```

Gets inserted into the editor like

```
Here is a link <a href="\&quot;example.com\&quot;">example.com</a>; this is a new line this is a new line this is a new line this is a new line this is a new line this is a new line this is a new line this is a new line this is a new line this is a new line this is a new line this is a new line
```

Comment: What does your representative data look like?

Comment: It gets inserted into the editor like this example Here is a link <a href="\&quot;http://www.example.com\&quot;">http://www.example.com</a> this is a new line this is a new line this is a new line this is a new line this is a new line this is a new line this is a new line this is a new line this is a new line this is a new line this is a new line this is a new line... I tried to add what it should look like but can't format in comments I guess. Each of those this is a new line should actually be in a new line.

Comment: You can't format text in the comments. Add it to your original question.

Comment: Updated original question.